# Search through column in excel for specific strings where the string is random in each cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am working in excel with a datasheet that is 1000 rows and 15 columns. Currently, in one of the columns, I have a lot of data mixed in with people names (see below for an example). I want to see how many times each person's name appears in the datasheet, so I can use it in a pivot table. There is no particular format or order to the way names appear. It is random.  Is there a way to code in excel to search through that whole column and give me a count of the amount of times each person's name appears?

```
Column D
21421Adam14234
2323xxx Bob 66
23 asjdxx Jacob 665
43 Tim 5935539
2394Bob 88
```

After some trial and error, I can generate a list of names, one per row and place them in a different column for comparison sake, if that makes it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have VBA tagged, but I don't know if there is a way to do this without it. I've built a custom function below. To implement it, take the following steps.

1) List desired names starting at column E1.

2) Insert this function into VBA Editor
    A) Presss Alt + F11
    B) Click Insert > Module from menu bar
    C) Copy this code into Module

```
Option Explicit

Function findString(rngString As Range, rngSearch As Range) As Long

Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Integer

i = 0

For Each cel In rngSearch
    If InStr(1, cel.Text, rngString.Value) > 0 Then 
        cel.offset(,-1) = rngString.Value 'places the name in cell to right of search range
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

findString = i

End Function
```

3) In F1 type the following formula

```
=findstring(E1,$D$1:$D$5)
```

4) Run the formula down column F to get the count of each desired name.

Comment: Could I also pick your brain for an additional request? I would also like to display the name next to each column (I would insert a new column C) that it was found in, for pivot table reasons.

Comment: see my edit. the only thing you have to make sure to do before entering the "=findstring(rngString, rngSearch)" function is that to have a blank column to the left of the search range.

Comment: I got an error that a value used in the formula was the wrong data type

Comment: change the .Value to .Text. See if that helps.

Comment: I changed both of the .Value to .Text in the formula, but am still getting a #VALUE, and the name is not appearing in the column next to it. I have both the left and right columns next to the range empty.

Comment: Jonny, since this is turning into an issue and it started as an additional question off the original, please post it as a new question and provide a data set (i.e. - post link to workbook) if you can. The community can address it a lot easier that way.

Comment: Also, see @Siddharth answer below. It's very useful for the original question, and probably the best way to go. For the 2nd question, you may need VBA to draw out the name, since it's such a tricky thing. But we can figure out the glitch in that on your new post.

Comment: I started another question thread which can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121326/how-to-use-one-coloumn-in-excel-as-a-search-parameter-in-another-column-to-outpu

Answer (score 5):

I know you have got your answer but why not use `COUNTIF` with Wild Cards? You don't need VBA for this :)

See this example

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,"*"&C1&"*")
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: +1 I was thinking about this, but it had been so long since I've used it I forget how to implement it, and got lazy! Thanks for providing and reminding me.