# How to use one column in excel as a search parameter in another column to output only certain strings

Tags: excel, vba

This question stems off another post I had. (see [Search through column in excel for specific strings where the string is random in each cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108719/search-through-column-in-excel-for-specific-strings-where-the-string-is-random-i))

[image: Workbook example]

Using the above image as reference, I am trying to search through column B (actually over 1000 lines) using column E as the "lookup values." The end goal would be for "just" the names to be displayed in column C. The trick is all the randomly generated characters the encompass the names. Below is what I would want the datasheet to look like. A formula or module should work, but the vlookup and other lookup function I can't get to work.

[image]

Comment: Do you only have 5 possible names in column E?

Comment: No, in the entire datasheet there are around 100. I am just giving a smaller example

Comment: How about this situation? Which one do you want to consider? Cell B3 has `xxxSamanthaxxx`. E3 has `Sam` and E4 has `Samantha` What should be the value in C3. Logically it has to be `Samantha` but how do you propose the code sees it? In such a scenario `INSTR` / `SEARCH` / `FIND` etc will fail

Comment: That situation will not occur. The actual names are more complicated. I appreciate the thought though

Comment: <OFF TOPIC> @SiddharthRout, how do you get the bold formatting with grey background in comments? Can't figure it out. </OFF TOPIC>

Comment: @Scott: use " ` " and " ` " around the word(s) without the double quotes, you want to bold.

Comment: i thought i did 'that' ... oh, i was using the wrong keys `Awesome!`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility, which may be easier to understand then assylias post initially, but also may be a bit more time consumptive (although with 1,000 rows, I don't think it will matter much) is below.

This requires that you name the range in column E as myNames (or whatever name you wish, just update the code - alternatively, you cuold just write Range("E1:E6")). Also, if you move the random values from column B, update that in the code as well.

```
Sub findString()

Dim celString As Range, rngString As Range, celSearch As Range, rngSearch As Range
Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = Sheets("Sheet1") 'change sheet reference to whatever your sheet name is

Set rngString = wks.Range("myNames")
Set rngSearch = Intersect(wks.UsedRange, wks.Range("B1").EntireColumn)

For Each celString In rngString
    For Each celSearch In rngSearch
        If InStr(1, celSearch.Text, celString.Value) > 0 Then
            celSearch.Offset(, 1) = celString.Value
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Since, I worked on your original question as well, I would suggest getting the counts through Siddharth's answer and then running this, or assylias's code above to get the names next to the columns. You could put a button the sheet, or just use the Macro dialog box to run the macro.

Comment: I am getting an error when trying to use the Sub, the varialbe UsedRange is not defined

Comment: I just edited my answer to be more precise and also compile correctly :)

Comment: I got a Run-time error'1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed. When debugging, it said rngString=Nothing

Comment: did you name the range where your unique names are as myNames. Alternatively, if you don't want to do that, just replace 'wks.Range("myNames")' with 'wks.Range("E1:E6")' or whatever your full range is.

Comment: Ok, when usuing myNames, it would not work; however, when specifing the range (e3:37), it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

For a worksheet function approach, you could enter in C3 and fill down this formula:

```
=LOOKUP(8^5,SEARCH(E$3:E$7,B3),E$3:E$7)
```

The constant 8^5=32768 is chosen to be larger than the maximum possible string length so that LOOKUP returns the last matching value. The formula returns #N/A if no string is found.

Comment: +1 I love SO. I learn something new almost everyday here now!

Comment: +1 I remember seeing this formula here as well. The best part is that its not an Array formula. [Go to link](http://www.mrexcel.com/pc18.shtml) . See Barry Houdini's answer to the problem.

Comment: I'd just add that the idea was not influenced by Barry Houdini - it occured to me independently a few years prior to that: http://excelbanter.com/showpost.php?p=404736&postcount=3